# Any way to use stackalloc while avoiding stackoverflow exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

In C# .NET, `stackalloc` keyword is very fascinating in order to avoid heap allocation. However, my concern is that using `stackalloc` might cause a `stackoverflow` exception. For the purpose of avoiding the exception, is there any good way to use `stackalloc` while avoiding `stackoverflow` exception? I originally came up with the following code, but I did not figure out how I should get the remaining stack size.

```
void Main()
{
    var remainingStackSize = //Get remaining stacksize somehow.

    var arraySize = 100;
    if (remainingStackSize > sizeof(byte) * arraySize) 
    {
        Span<byte> numbers = stackalloc byte[arraySize];
    }
    else 
    {
        Span<byte> numbers = new byte[arraySize];
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no way to retrieve the maximum stack size, nor the starting stack address, nor the current stack address in .NET. You could write and compile a C function which extracts the stack pointer from the SP/RSP register, and then start a new thread with your known max stack size. From there, at the start of your `Main()`, you could retrieve the stack pointer, store it to some global static field, then retrieve it again whenever you want to measure your current stack location. Subtract the pointers, then subtract from your known max stack size. (I haven't tried this yet.)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc):

> The amount of memory available on the stack is limited. If you allocate too much memory on the stack, a StackOverflowException is thrown. To avoid that, follow the rules below:
>
> Limit the amount of memory you allocate with stackalloc. Because the amount of memory available on the stack depends on the environment in which the code is executed, be conservative when you define the actual limit value.
>
> Avoid using stackalloc inside loops. Allocate the memory block outside a loop and reuse it inside the loop.

See also [How much stack usage is too much?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/310658/how-much-stack-usage-is-too-much)